# Embed report chart in a Lightning component to parametrize its filters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reporting, custom-report-type, charts, report-chart

I have a report which doesn't filter by Lookups but by String field values. I want to show this chart on the record pages of a related record. But I am not sure how I pass in filter criteria into the charts report.

I also didn't find examples of how to wrap native charts in a Lightning component where I can pass in parameters.

Would this work? Can you point me to example code?

Comment: By native charts do you mean 3rd party  charts libraries

Comment: No I mean standard Salesforce charts.